# TfidfVectorizer processes first document only

Tags: tfidfvectorizer

I'm getting TD-IDF weights only on the 1st document in the list. The rest are zeros!

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(docs)

print(tfidf_vectorizer.idf_)

pd.DataFrame(X[0].T.todense(), index=tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=["tfidf"]).sort_values(by=["tfidf"],ascending=False).head(10)
```

For list:

```
  docs=[
          "the world dog",
          "the cat hello",
          "the foo hello",
         ]
```

The output

```
[1.69314718 1.69314718 1.69314718 1.28768207 1.         1.69314718]
        tfidf
dog     0.652491
world   0.652491
the     0.385372
cat     0.000000
foo     0.000000
hello   0.000000
```

After swapping the first two lines

```
  docs=[
          "the cat hello",
          "the world dog",
          "the foo hello",
         ]
```

The output becomes:

```
[1.69314718 1.69314718 1.69314718 1.28768207 1.         1.69314718]

        tfidf
cat     0.720333
hello   0.547832
the     0.425441
dog     0.000000
foo     0.000000
world   0.000000
```

Can anyone offer insight into this issue?

Comment: Isn't it because you're filtering the first value of X here? (X[0]): `pd.DataFrame(X[0].T.todense(), index=tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=["tfidf"]).sort_values(by=["tfidf"],ascending=False).head(10)`

Comment: Right. Thank you. Was misled by an example online. I wanted to get results for the entire corpus.

Comment: Hey @kb88, I edited my answer, did it work?

Answer (score 0):

it might be because when you're making a DataFrame you're only using the first value of the TF-IDF's sparse matrix `X[0].T.todense()` should be `X.T.todense()`

Also you'd do better if you kept the fitted TFIDF into another variable so you can transform new incoming data for testing:

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer().fit(docs)
X = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(docs)

print(tfidf_vectorizer.idf_)
```

Now, since you don't have 1 line, you can't transpose and state only 1 column, you'll need to convert to an array an set the columns as the tf-idf possible values. The indes will be numeric.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), 
                  columns=tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names())

print(df.head(10)) # or display() if you're in jupyter
```

Comment: X.T.todense() is a matrix (n_tokens x n_docs) 
`ValueError: Shape of passed values is (6, 3), indices imply (6, 1)`